# is there any resource upon software protection by obstructing code flow analysis on arm platform?

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, reverse-engineering, armv8

In the world of x86, early return is a very common effect way
to confuse the dissembler. http://www.ouah.org/linux-anti-debugging.txt

Jacob Baines have implemented a state of the art early return tech with jmp to obstructing code flow analysis, which work very good to cheat IDA pro or radare2. https://github.com/antire-book/antire_book

However, It seems impossible to port this x86 technique(in asm) to arm.

I wonder is there any anti-debugging technique to fight with the static analysis ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "early return"?  The phrase doesn't appear in either of the documents you linked.

Comment: It's true that you can't jump into the middle of an instruction, because ARM64 instructions are all the same length and must be aligned.  (There might conceivably be a chance with Thumb2 in 32-bit mode.)  If you're asking for all possible anti-debugging techniques, I think that is too broad.

Comment: @NateEldredge  "early return" is Return Pointer Abuse. Briefly, pushing an address onto the stack and immeaditely return.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it would be very easy since you can load the program counter (`R15`) with any value you want. So maybe try this:

```
adr r1,goHere  @I believe this loads the address "goHere"
mov pc,r1      @this is our JMP command


goHere:
```

Comment: An indirect jump with a constant target doesn't make naive disassemblers like `objdump -d` stumble, nor does it stop a debugger from single-stepping past this code.  It might slow down something like IDA that makes flow-control graphs for blocks of code with arrows connecting them, if it doesn't realize that the only possible `r1` value for that instruction is `goHere`.  That's pretty, but it's not nothing.  Still, you should explain exactly what this does / doesn't accomplish in terms of slowing down reverse-engineering.

Comment: To be fair, half the things mentioned in the question weren't *static* analysis, they were things like runtime detection or blocking of a debugger.  But anyway, ARM in Thumb mode should be able to jump into the middle of a 32-bit instruction and fool `objdump`.  That's be worth an upvote.  (I didn't downvote, that was someone else)